# MySQL SELECT DISTINCT ORDER BY problem

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, left-join, distinct

To begin with I have 4 tables I am dealing with.

I have a **classes** table that is a 1->N relationship with a **sections** table which also has a 1->N relationship with a **lessons** table.

So to put it in perpective:

- **Classes**

  - **Sections**

    - **Lessons**

The last table is an **activityLog**, when the student accesses a lesson this is recorded using the following:

ActivityLog Row -> **actorID (user ID), classID, sectionID, lessonID**

I want to pull out the last 5 **unique** lessons the student has visited.  I tried using both DISTINCT and GROUP BY without success.

The same records are being returned each time, not the latest classes that they have visited.

Using GROUP BY

```
SELECT activityLog.actorID, activityLog.activityDate,
        strClasses.classID, strClasses.className,
        strSections.sectionID, strSections.sectionName,
        strLessons.lessonID, strLessons.lessonName

FROM activityLog            
LEFT JOIN strClasses ON strClasses.classID = activityLog.classID
LEFT JOIN strSections ON strSections.sectionID = activityLog.sectionID
LEFT JOIN strLessons ON strLessons.lessonID = activityLog.lessonID
WHERE activityLog.activityTypeID = 6 AND activityLog.actorID = 3
GROUP BY activityLog.lessonID
ORDER BY activityLog.activityDate DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Using DISTINCT

```
SELECT DISTINCT activityLog.actorID,
        strClasses.classID, strClasses.className,
        strSections.sectionID, strSections.sectionName,
        strLessons.lessonID, strLessons.lessonName
FROM activityLog            
LEFT JOIN strClasses ON strClasses.classID = activityLog.classID
LEFT JOIN strSections ON strSections.sectionID = activityLog.sectionID
LEFT JOIN strLessons ON strLessons.lessonID = activityLog.lessonID
WHERE activityLog.activityTypeID = 6 AND activityLog.actorID = 3
ORDER BY activityLog.activityDate DESC
LIMIT 5
```

I cannot figure out why the latest records are not being displayed.

Comment: Do you have example input and output data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your change, how does this suit you?

```
SELECT activityLog.actorID, activityLog.activityDate,
        strClasses.classID, strClasses.className,
        strSections.sectionID, strSections.sectionName,
        strLessons.lessonID, strLessons.lessonName
FROM activityLog            
LEFT JOIN strClasses ON strClasses.classID = activityLog.classID
LEFT JOIN strSections ON strSections.sectionID = activityLog.sectionID
LEFT JOIN strLessons ON strLessons.lessonID = activityLog.lessonID
WHERE activityLog.activityTypeID = 6 AND activityLog.actorID = 3
AND activityLog.activityDate = (SELECT MAX(activityDate) FROM activityLog AS lookup WHERE lessonID = activityLog.lessonID)
ORDER BY activityLog.activityDate DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Based on your description, I'm not sure why you're using `LEFT JOIN`, but I've left it in just in case.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my description.  I needed the last 5 unique lessons accessed.  I am still not getting the correct order.  The date that they were accessed doesn't seem to make a difference.  I get 5 unique results, but they are stuck in the order they were originally accessed.  Like if I access the lesson for the last result, it should be moved back to the top.

Comment: It works!  Thank you so much! I was wondering about doing a subquery, but I don't have much experience at that.

Answer (score 0):

Try group by like below
GROUP BY activityLog.classID,activityLog.sectionID,activityLog.lessonID

I think it will work, or just sent me create scripts for these I will create that query

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's got to be a datetime in the ActivityLog I hope... so Try this:

```
 Select s.Name, c.ClassName
 From Students s
     left Join On Classes c
          On c.ClassId In 
               (Select Distinct ClassId From Classes
                Where (Select Count(Distinct ClassId) From Classes ic
                         Join ActivityLog l On l.UserId = s.UserId
                            And l.ClassId = c.ClassId                         
                       Where classId = c.ClassId
                          And activityDateTime > l.activityDateTime) 
                    < 5)
```

Comment: `activityLog.activityDate` is mentioned in the SQL examples.